# How to get excerpt of the recent posts

Tags: excerpt, recent-posts

Right now, i am using code below to show title and its link of recent posts from my custom post category, but for one of my category i want to show excerpt, how can i achieve that.

CODE i am using to display title:

```
<?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>'jokes'));
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Codex: [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[`wp_trim_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt)** to get the excerpt of the content.

You can use it inside your loop to get the excerpt of each post

> the string provided to a maximum of 55 words if it is more then a [...] will be added to the end of the string.

```
<?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>'jokes'));
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        $excerpt = wp_trim_excerpt( $recent['post_content']); // $excerpt contains the excerpt of the concerned post
        echo $excerpt;
    }
?>
```